# Is it necessary to include a factor (fitted as a smooth-factor interaction) as a parametric term within a gam?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am interested in investigating a non-linear temporal trend in a data set and so I would like to use the R package `mgcv` to fit the following GAM:

```
model1 <- gam(Variable ~ s(Date, by = Site.Factor), data = data)
```

where `Variable` is the continuous variable of interest, `Site.Factor` is a factor with two levels and `Date` is a continuous variable.

I have read that know that because of the inclusion of the by factor within the smoothing function, differences in the means of the two factor levels are not accounted for. I should therefore include `Site.Factor` as a parametric term like so:

```
model2 <- gam(Variable ~ Site.Factor + s(Date, by = Site.Factor), data = data)
```

However, whilst I might expect the influence of `Site.Factor` on the smooth to be significant, I do not expect the means of each level of the factor to be significant. Do I still need to include the factor separately within the model as in `model1`, or would `model2` be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know that the **populations** from which your data are drawn have **exactly** the same mean then yes, you should include the term `Site.Factor` as a fixed effect term, whether that difference *in sample* is significant or not.